# Is there a way to get the size of data at firebase URL?

Tags: firebase

How do I get the size of the data stored at a firebase URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean the size of the data stored at a URL.

We don't currently have an API to return just the size of data stored at a location. We do provide the total size of your data in Firebase, if you look in the Analytics tab in Forge. If you want the size a specific URL though, you'll need to download the data and measure it yourself (for now).

Comment: yup that's the answer that I was looking for, have also edited the questions. Thanks! :)

Comment: by the way, is full offline support for firebase on top of your list for the next release? :)